# server encountered error while processing large data in Google App Engine java

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, connection-timeout

My code is written in jsp for importing product from CSV file .

The process is working fine for less then 300 - 400 products importing. But when I try with large number of rows like 1000 or more, it gives me below error because of its long process.

I am using Google App Engine with Google cloud SQL. This problem does not occur only with this product import system. But I observed many times,  it is due to long process time execution.

**Note :** Working well in local system but problem occurs after deploying on google app server

500 Server Error

## Error: Server Error

### The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

Is there any special configuration in jsp or servlet file ?
 Is this issue related to any session expiry time ? (i also tried with session.setMaxInactiveInterval(500000))
Is there any configuration on google-app-engine ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

if your import takes longer than 60 seconds your issue is documented at [1].

The Google App Engine request timer (Java/Python/Go) ensures that requests have a finite lifespan and do not get caught in an infinite loop. Currently, the deadline for requests to frontend instances is 60 seconds. (Backend instances have no corresponding limit.) Every request, including warmup (request to /_ah/warmup) and loading requests ("loading_request=1" log header), is subject to this restriction.

If a request fails to return within 60 seconds and a DeadlineExceededError is thrown and not caught, the request is aborted and a 500 internal server error is returned. If the DeadlineExceededError is caught but a response is not produced quickly enough (you have less than a second), the request is aborted and a 500 internal server error is returned.

Hope this helps.
Ciao
Paolo

Links:
[1] - https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: Just to add to that, if the task is expected to take a long time, it could be run as a Task (which have longer deadlines).  See also the deadlines in the table on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) about different module scaling options.

Comment: @tx802 Tasks are still limited (mind you, 10 minutes should be enough, but still). Just for the sake of completion, OP can use back-end instances with modules for jobs that might need more than 10 minutes